# Why getting this error in tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

```
m = tf.Variable(0.44)
b = tf.Variable(0.87)
error = 0
for x, y in zip(x_data, y_label):
    y_hat = m*x+b
    error +=(y-y_label)**2
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(error)
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001)
>   ----> 2 train = optimizer.minimize(error)
>
> C:\Users\ASUS
>   PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py
>   in minimize(self, loss, global_step, var_list, gate_gradients,
>   aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops, name, grad_loss)
>       341         aggregation_method=aggregation_method,
>       342         colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops,
>   --> 343         grad_loss=grad_loss)
>       344 
>       345     vars_with_grad = [v for g, v in grads_and_vars if g is not None]
>
> C:\Users\ASUS
>   PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py
>   in compute_gradients(self, loss, var_list, gate_gradients,
>   aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops, grad_loss)
>       392                        "Optimizer.GATE_OP, Optimizer.GATE_GRAPH.  Not %s" %
>       393                        gate_gradients)
>   --> 394     self._assert_valid_dtypes([loss])
>       395     if grad_loss is not None:
>       396       self._assert_valid_dtypes([grad_loss])
>
> C:\Users\ASUS
>   PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py
>   in _assert_valid_dtypes(self, tensors)
>       541     valid_dtypes = self._valid_dtypes()
>       542     for t in tensors:
>   --> 543       dtype = t.dtype.base_dtype
>       544       if dtype not in valid_dtypes:
>       545         raise ValueError(
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `optimizer.minimize` accepts only Tensor variables.

The rest of the code is not actually correct as well, it should look similar to:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
m = tf.Variable(0.44)
b = tf.Variable(0.87)

y_hat = m * x + b

error = tf.squared_difference(y, y_hat)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(error)
number_of_iterations = 100000
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in xrange(0, number_of_iterations):
        sess.run(train, {x:x_data, y: y_label}}
        #If you want to see the loss:
        #loss = sess.run(error,{x:x_data, y: y_label})
        #print("Current loss is:" + str(loss))
```